# How to display shutil data using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using an e-ink display and want to make it display disk utilization. How can I use PIL to display that when it only allows me to input a single line of text?

```
import epd4in2
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import shutil

EPD_WIDTH = 400
EPD_HEIGHT = 300

def main():
    epd = epd4in2.EPD()
    epd.init()

    # For simplicity, the arguments are explicit numerical coordinates
    image = Image.new('1', (EPD_WIDTH, EPD_HEIGHT), 1)    # 1: clear the frame
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf', 24)
    #draw.rectangle((0, 6, 400, 30), fill = 255)

    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

    S = ("Total: %d GB" % (total // (2**30))) + '\n' + \
    ("Used: %d GB" % (used // (2**30))) + '\n' + \
    ("Free: %d GB" % (free // (2**30)))


    draw.text((100, 10), S, font = font, fill = 0)
    #draw.rectangle((200, 80, 360, 280), fill = 0)
    #draw.arc((240, 80, 380, 220), 0, 360, fill = 255)
    #draw.rectangle((0, 80, 160, 280), fill = 255)
    #draw.arc((40, 80, 180, 220), 0, 360, fill = 0)

    epd.display_frame(epd.get_frame_buffer(image))

    image = Image.open('wildfireDLN2.bmp')
    epd.display_frame(epd.get_frame_buffer(image))

    # You can get frame buffer from an image or import the buffer directly:
    #epd.display_frame(imagedata.MONOCOLOR_BITMAP)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I included the code I made to display the disk usage, but the only thing the e-ink display prints is the "Hello World" line. Is there something in PIL that allows me to use the disk usage code?

Comment: Your `main()` will never run, you enter an infinite loop before it starts.

Comment: Maybe you could sketch how the display is supposed to look because it is not that clear from your answer! Is it supposed to have words or a bar-graph or something? Which e-ink display is it? What are the rectangles and arcs that you are trying to draw? Why do you think you can only write one line on an image in PIL?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong file at first

Comment: Please ensure your post a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example** of your code as required by StackOverflow rules. *"Minimal"* means it should not contain a load of unnecessary stuff (e.g. drawing arcs and rectangles). *"Complete"* means that if you read a BMP file, you should provide it or something similar, and that you should identify the hardware you are using and the expected and actual results and all error messages.